# OpenCV: Auomatic resize of the window to the image displayed

Tags: python, qt, opencv, python-2.x

Is there a way to force the window displayed by OpenCV (`cv2.imshow()`)when displaying an image to fit to the width and height of the image without the need to resize by the mouse it for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass [CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) when creating the namedWindow (or `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` if you import `cv2` instead of `cv`)

Here is an example:

```
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE) 
# or cv.namedWindow("window",cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow("window", yourimage)
```

Answer (score 1):

In opencv 4.0.0 the below solution works:

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("myImage", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
image = cv2.imread("./image.jpg")
cv2.imshow("myImage", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This does not work either :(