# Why resizing the window to the same dimmension actually resizes it?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a similar problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180764/opencv-python-image-too-big-to-display) When I use `cv2.imshow` the image is bigger than my screen.

What to do? I tried several of the answers without success until I tried [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66512528/4451521) dealing with `cv2.resizeWindow`

However I got some surprising result. Even when I use the above function to resize it to the *same* height and width of the original (so no resize) the window is resized and I can see the entire image

Why is this happening?

Edit: just in case, I used `cv2.namedWindow("Original",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)`

Comment: did you compile opencv with qt support ?

Comment: windows can't be larger than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can see the entire image now is because of the `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` flag you passed into the `cv2.namedWindow()` function.

This displays the image, cropped if it is too big to fit into the screen:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This displays the image, scaled down to a convenient size (and the window can be resized):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This displays the image, scaled down to the specified size... *if* the specified size can be fit into your screen; else, it will scale the image to be the size of your screen (and the window can be resized):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
h, w, _ = img.shape
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.resizeWindow("Image", w, h)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### So basically,

it is impossible for the window to be bigger than your screen, but the  `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` flag made it so that instead of having the image *cropped* to fit the screen, it got *scaled* to fit the screen.