# Video does not fit. how to fit the frame to screen opencv-python version 4.6.0.66

Tags: python, opencv, resolution

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mpPose.Pose()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/1.mp4')
pTime = 0

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pose.process(imgRGB)
    print(results.pose_landmarks)
    if results.pose_landmarks:
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

cTime = time.time()
fps = 15/(cTime-pTime)
pTime = cTime

cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)),(70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255,0,0),3)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

[image]

This is the real resolution of the video:

[image]

Comment: `namedWindow("image", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV & Python - Image too big to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180764/opencv-python-image-too-big-to-display)